# Javascript Changes Site Width

Tags: javascript, html, hubspot

When I insert this code into my header:

```
<script src="//use.typekit.net/tue6amj.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

It changes the width of my site. All my content is still the same width, but I'm able to scroll to the right, off the page. See: http://inkliss.hs-sites.com

The output of the HTML seems to insert above the header:

```
<html class="no-js wf-proximanova-i7-active wf-proximanova-n7-active wf-active" lang="en">
```

and that makes the page pop out.

So is this a problem with Hubspot? I'm adding the script to the header code section. Or is there a way that I can wrap the java in another tag that won't let it break the page?

Comment: Which browser are you using? This seems fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: you can use dev tools (right click in chrome, inspect element) to inspect the element to determine exactly which added class is causing this and write a css override to handle it. PS java is not javascript.

Comment: Kai Qing is correct.  You are experiencing overflow issues...and yes twacarter it is occuring in chrome but only for a brief second as you scroll down the page.  Once you find which element is causing the overflow issue you'll be able to use css to hide overflow.  Or you could always try body {overflow-x:hidden;} just to see if it works.

Comment: Using Firefox, and I use firebug to inspect. That's the output HTML that's breaking the theme. If I remove the code from the header, the page stops breaking.

Comment: The Overflow-x worked perfectly. You rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kai Qing is correct. You are experiencing overflow issues...and yes twacarter it is occuring in chrome but only for a brief second as you scroll down the page. Once you find which element is causing the overflow issue you'll be able to use css to hide overflow. Or you could always try body `{overflow-x:hidden;}` just to see if it works.